# Symfony2: event listener breaks debug toolbar on login page

Tags: php, symfony, events, authentication, toolbar

I have Symfony2 application. I want to set locale when user logs in to last_login_locale, which is stored in db.

Here services.yml:

```
login_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\AuthListener
    arguments:
        - @request_stack
        - @users_manager
        - @session
    tags:
        -  { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Here AuthListener.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\AuthenticationEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use AppBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class AuthListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $requestStack;
    protected $usersManager;
    protected $session;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, DBALManager $usersManager, Session $session)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->usersManager = $usersManager;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS => 'onAuthenticationSuccess',
        ];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess($event)
    {
        // even empty function cause error
        // here i get locale from db and set to session

    }
}
```

I get [GET] /_wdt/f3a2ee 404 Not found error even if I leave onAuthenticationSuccess empty. Error occurs only on /login page.
[image]

Comment: as still this question is upvoted, I will mention that in this case it was something related to security listeners

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working fine for me on Symfony 2.7

```
namespace Acme\YourBundle\Listeners;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\AuthenticationEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent;

class AuthenticationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(AuthenticationEvent  $event) {
        if(!$event->getAuthenticationToken() instanceof AnonymousToken) {
            // Apply action only when the user is actually authenticated and not a guest.
            // If the user is authenticated, the token will be `UsernamePasswordToken`.
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS => 'onAuthenticationSuccess'
        );
    }
}
```

In `services.yml`:

```
acme.security.authentication_event_listener:
    class: Acme\YourBundle\Listeners\AuthenticationListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, event: security.authentication.success, method: onAuthenticationSuccess }
```

Comment: it looks the same to mine))

Comment: i tried as described here http://www.webtipblog.com/create-authentication-listener-symfony-2/ but it didn't work :( I mean this one: `- { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onAuthenticationSuccess }`

Comment: Is your `services.yml` being imported in `config.yml`?

Comment: I think the tutorial you're looking at might be a bit outdated. I've updated my answer with an example code I've tried and seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I speak spanish but i will try to answer in english, im sorry if i write something wrong.

I think this error is because you have some problem with the classes that you have as parameters in __construct, so you need to check these classes to see if there is an error inside them.

I dont know why your DBAL class seems to have problems,as it is highlighted in blue.

In my case the problem was that i forgot the namespace of a class and i had the same error.

I hope this help you.